# Get current ApplicationUser in layout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC5, created `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` with custom properties. Now I want to get a custom property (Avatar) in layout.cshtml to show the logged in user image in different layout (header, sidebar) views. How do I do that?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

Currently I am using `@User.Identity.Name` to get logged user name in my views. I also want the user image.

How can I get that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you cast the object first @(((AppliactionUser)User.Identity).Avatar)  I have solved this by creating a base viewmodel that has my user class in it. I'm using the base class for multiple properties that I use in my layout.

Comment: @Martin Doesn't work. Throws `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` exception

Comment: Then I would create a base viewmodel that you use in each of your viewmodels. This will give you access to all your properties you need in your layout page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add avatar property as IdentityClaim

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public string Avatar { get; set; }
     public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
     {
           var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
           userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("avatar", this.Avatar));
           return userIdentity;
     }
}
```

Inside razor view you can access it like this

```
@{
    var avatar = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("avatar");
}
```

Comment: `avatar.Value` contains the value